# Mail app no longer accepts my Exchange password (macOS Mojave)

Tags: mail.app, email, exchange

Two days ago Mac Mail (Version 12.4 on Mojave 10.14.6) no longer accepted my Exchange password. I've tried everything I can think of:

- Changed password in Office 365 Admin Center.
- Exchange account still works fine on my iPhone, as well as in Web Mail.
- Removed Mail Account and deleted account under Internet Accounts.
- When I try to recreate Internet Account, it recognizes my user name, but when I enter the password it gets stuck on a grey window with a spinning gear.
- Back in mail, the Account is there, but again it tells me the password is bad. I've
  retried these steps many, many times.
- Safe Boot does not help.
- The mail account works fine in Outlook for Mac (but I prefer to use Mail
  which we use business-wide).
- I created a test user account to see if it's a User library issue. In the test account, the same problem occurs.
- I have a 2nd Exchange account which continues to work fine. I was able to recreate that 2nd Exchange account in my test User account as well.

Because the problem persists in a new test Mac account, I don't believe it's a Mac user account issue. Because the Exchange account works fine on my iPhone, as well as in Outlook, I don't think it's an Exchange account issue. And because I have a 2nd Exchange account working fine in Mail, I don't think it's a Mail/Exchange issue.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be incredibly grateful!

Comment: Is the second Exchange account connected to the same domain? Just guessing, but I wonder if this is related somehow to the fact that Microsoft has started disabling basic authentication for Exchange Web Services (see this announcement: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437), which is the protocol used by the Mail app. According to paragraph "One-Time Re-Enablement" in the linked document, you can re-enable it and use until end of December 2022 (check the document for details).

Comment: Thank you Jaume! Yes, it is connected to the same domain. In my digging around I learned about the Microsoft changes you mention, though I didn't understand them 100%. I went through the process they describe and "think" I was able to re-enable EWS. That didn't help.

Comment: Yes, I just checked my 365 Admin Center and re-ran the test they provide; I no longer see EWS as disabled. I tried to add my account and it still doesn't work so I don't believe that's the issue. Thank you again for the suggestion though.

Comment: Update - I tried to add my Exchange account onto a different computer, running the same OS/Mail versions as me (Mojave 10.14.6, Mail 12.4). It did NOT work. So that ruled out issues on just my machine. I then tried to set it up on a newer Mac running Monterey, and it DID work. So maybe Jaume was correct and it is related to the new Authentication requirements.

Comment: However, Apple reports that "10.14 supports Microsoft Modern Authentication workflows of Exchange online tenants. OAuth can be used for Office 365 accounts with Modern Authentication enabled." (https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/integrate-with-microsoft-exchange-dep158966b23/web). So maybe I need to make some changes on the Exchange side or on my Mac to allow it to work on my 10.14 machine? I'd prefer not to upgrade as we rely on an older database that doesn't run on newer OS's.

Comment: Yes, I saw that article too, and the fact that the second account works makes the issue more puzzling. Can you check in Mail Preferences > [Exchange Account] > Server Settings > Advanced Exchange Settings if "Allow insecure authentication" is enabled? Can you try enabling modern authentication (you can revert the change if necessary) (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/enable-or-disable-modern-authentication-in-exchange-online for more information)? Can you check the Exchange logs and if the second account is configured differently in Exchange?

Comment: Thank you Jaume! FYI, "Allow insecure authentication" was not enabled. But, would you believe it, I tried to recreate the account yet again the morning, and as if by magic, it worked! I didn't do anything differently or make any changes to any settings. Part of me wishes I knew what happened, but for now I am just very relieved and will take the win! I greatly appreciate your responses and am glad to have this thread to look back on should the problem return. In the meantime I wish you all the best!

Comment: That's great news! While I really hope the issue is solved permanently, couldn't it be that the one-time re-enablement is active? You may want to dig deeper and compare the settings of the first and second accounts and check the logs, just in case.